# jquery version of tinymce 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce-4

I am trying to use jquery version of tinymce 4.

```
<script src="http://tinymce.cachefly.net/4.0/jquery.tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
    $("textarea").tinymce();
});
</script>
<textarea>Your content here.</textarea>
```

But when I run the page, I get the error message `tinymce is not defined`. How can I fix it? Thank you.

Comment: maybe this help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21434388/how-do-i-use-tinymce-jquery-package-and-what-is-the-difference-with-tinymce-jque

Comment: look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23221516/how-to-run-tinymce-in-jquery-modal-dialog/23222406#23222406

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add these files:

```
<script src="/js/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/js/tinymce/jquery.tinymce.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you [include some explanation along with it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/159034) to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked. Thanks!