# How to select a dom element that was added by prototype with jquery?

Tags: jquery, dom, select

I want to check if a prototype and my jQuery script are compatible. In the prototype application some divs with a textarea are added. After `document.ready` I can't access it. I also tried `j('#the_parent_div_where_the_divs_are_added').bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function () {...});` but that also didn't work. Any ideas how I could realise a focus-function for the prototype added textareas?

This is my jquery focus function which works fine with static textarea elements but not with the dynamically added:

```
j('.cright_txtarea').focus(function () {
       id = j(this).attr('id');
       text = j(this).html();
       j("#modal_form_div").dialog("open");
       tinyMCE.activeEditor.dom.setHTML(text);
       return false;
});
```

This function transports the text of the textarea in a tinymce editor in a modal window.

Comment: Event delegation will resolve what you are asking (cue the onslaught of answers), but I thought tinymce used an iframe.  Does it not?

Comment: As a note, you can use just `this.id` to get an `id` from `this`, rather than `j(this).attr('id')`.

Comment: @Archer: Thx, I tried j('#parent_div div .cright_txtarea').on('focusin', function (e) {                       event.preventDefault(); ... }); but it didn't work so far. But maybe the selector is wrong. There is a div in between without any class or id. But I'll continue trying. And I don't know if TinyMCE normally uses an iframe. In my case I have many small textareas - small as text input fields. I didn't want to destroy the layout so I have a popup tinymce ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think delegation is the way to go, this is how you would do it:

```
j(document).on('focus', '.cright_txtarea', function () {
    // do stuff
});
```

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/d5dZ7/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what your question/problem is. But from what I gather, along with your JavaScript snippet, I have a hunch that your having concurrency issues.

For example:

```
j("#modal_form_div").dialog("open");
tinyMCE.activeEditor.dom.setHTML(text);
```

Here, you ask the `dialog` to `open`, then run yout `tinyMCE` command to copy the text. The problem is, `tinyMCE` might run it's command before the dialog has finished opening.

Also, the element you're looking for might not exist yet for the same reason. If you're looking for a TinyMCE editor or part of it, it might not exist on `document.ready`.

**Solution:** callbacks

Do stuff *after* the jQuery UI dialog (I assume) has opened:
http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#event-open

Do stuff *after* the TinyMCE editor has loaded:
[http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:init_instance_callback](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3ainit_instance_callback)

Comment: Thx but the problem is only about the selection at the moment. I guess the dialog would open if I just could select the textareas. The problem with the tinymce is that it's a huge library and it can't be imported in a fiddle. But it is something like the answer of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23221516/how-to-run-tinymce-in-jquery-modal-dialog But I'm not sure which event listener or whatever to use to select the textarea :(

Comment: Right, what I'm saying is that the object you're trying to select might not exist *when* you're trying to select it. Also, JSFiddle has an "External Resources" option on the right-hand nav bar where you can include a URL to a TinyMCE CDN. I've got you started right here: http://jsfiddle.net/f64UJ/

Comment: Yeah, I know. But you cant import the whole library with all the subdirectories, plugins etc. that's why I didnt do it ;) I already know that the textareas do not exist yet after document.ready is called. Archer gave me the tip with delegation and if I could bind the textareas that could be the soulution